# Custom 'typesafe' Int Types

Tags: kotlin

What I would like to have is two different integer types which are semantically distinguishable.

E.g. in this code a 'Meter' type and a 'Pixel' int type

```
typealias Meter = Int
typealias Pixel = Int

fun Meter.toPixel() = this * 100
fun Pixel.toMeter() = this / 100

fun calcSquareMeters(width: Meter, height: Meter) = width * height
fun calcSquarePixels(width: Pixel, height: Pixel) = width * height

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val pixelWidth: Pixel = 50
    val pixelHeight: Pixel = 50

    val meterWidth: Meter = 50
    val meterHeight: Meter = 50

    calcSquareMeters(pixelWidth, pixelHeight) // (a) this should not work

    pixelWidth.toPixel() // (b) this should not work
}
```

The problem with this solution is

(a) that I can call calcSquareMeters with my 'Pixel' type which I don't want to be possible and

(b) that I can call the toPixel() extension function which I only want to have for my 'Meter' type on my 'Pixel' type which I don't want to be possible.

I guess this is the intended behaviour of typealias, so I guess to achieve my goal I have to use something different than typealias...

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057914/5427663): If you have a lot of common functionality between the two types and don't want to duplicate it, you can work with an interface:

```kotlin
interface MetricType<T> {
    val value: Int

    fun new(value: Int): T
}

data class Meter(override val value: Int) : MetricType<Meter> {
    override fun new(value: Int) = Meter(value)
}

data class Pixel(override val value: Int) : MetricType<Pixel> {
    override fun new(value: Int) = Pixel(value)
}
```

Like this, you can easily define operations on the base interface, such as addition, subtraction and scaling:

```
operator fun <T : MetricType<T>> T.plus(rhs: T) = new(this.value + rhs.value)
operator fun <T : MetricType<T>> T.minus(rhs: T) = new(this.value + rhs.value)
operator fun <T : MetricType<T>> T.times(rhs: Int) = new(this.value * rhs)
```

The combination of interface and generics ensures type safety, so you do not accidentally mix types:

```
fun test() {
    val m = Meter(3)
    val p = Pixel(7)

    val mm = m + m // OK
    val pp = p + p // OK
    val mp = m + p // does not compile
}
```

Keep in mind that this solution comes at a runtime cost due to the virtual functions (compared to rewriting the operators for each type separately). This in addition to the overhead of object creation.

Comment: I was trying to define those operators in a common way... Extensions on generics are the solution I somehow missed. Good job with those!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, typealiases don't guarantee this sort of type safety. You'll have to create wrapper classes around an `Int` value instead to achieve this - it's a good idea to make these data classes so that equality comparisons work on them:

```
data class Meter(val value: Int)
data class Pixel(val value: Int)
```

Creation of instances of these classes can be solved with extension properties:

```
val Int.px
    get() = Pixel(this)

val pixelWidth: Pixel = 50.px
```

The only problematic thing is that you can no longer directly perform arithmetic operations on `Pixel` and `Meter` instances, for example, the conversion functions would now look like this:

```
fun Meter.toPixel() = this.value * 100
```

Or the square calculations like this:

```
fun calcSquareMeters(width: Meter, height: Meter) = width.value * height.value
```

If you really need direct operator use, you can still define those, but it will be quite tedious:

```
class Meter(val value: Int) {
    operator fun times(that: Meter) = this.value * that.value
}

fun calcSquareMeters(width: Meter, height: Meter) = width * height
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposal (not yet guaranteed to be accepted) to add `inline class`es for this purpose. I.e.

```
@InlineOnly inline class Meter(val value: Int)
```

will really be an `Int` at runtime.

See https://github.com/zarechenskiy/KEEP/blob/28f7fdbe9ca22db5cfc0faeb8c2647949c9fd61b/proposals/inline-classes.md and https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/104.

Answer (score 0):

From kotlin [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html):

> Type aliases do not introduce new types. They are equivalent to the corresponding underlying types. When you add typealias Predicate and use Predicate in your code, the Kotlin compiler always expand it to (Int) -> Boolean. Thus you can pass a variable of your type whenever a general function type is required and vice versa

This means that there isn't possible check over your typealias, and you are rally declaring your extensions functions as:

```
fun Int.toPixel() = this * 100
fun Int.toMeter() = this / 100

fun calcSquareMeters(width: Int, height: Int) = width * height
fun calcSquarePixels(width: Int, height: Int) = width * height
```

I fear the only way to achieve that you want is implementing an extra class for each type.

Answer (score 0):

I would also go with the solution from [TheOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059224/9346583). But I would like to add the `inline` keyword to the operator functions. By doing so you could avoid a virtual function call when ever you use this operators.

```kotlin
inline operator fun <T : MetricType<T>> T.plus(rhs: T) = new(this.value + rhs.value)
inline operator fun <T : MetricType<T>> T.minus(rhs: T) = new(this.value + rhs.value)
inline operator fun <T : MetricType<T>> T.times(rhs: Int) = new(this.value * rhs)
```